# BeautifulSoup get_text() not returning all text

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape from a forum site that is littered with random silly html gems, and am unable to get everything I need from it. Most of the content scrapes just fine (when the html isn't too ugly) but for the problematic posts, I'm only getting the text from the first  tag. Can you help me figure out how to get all the text from the entire post? Thank you!

The HTML for the post looks something like this:
This is all contained in a  tag from a

```
<div class="PostMessageBody">Mike,</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
    "lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum"
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
    "lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum"
    </div>
</div>
```

Most of the posts make use of the 
 tag, but every once in a while, this gem pops up instead. When it does, the only part that gets scraped by BS is the first div, and the string "Mike," is the only part that gets scraped, however I am also needing to scrape the "lorem ipsum" content.

I'm using beautifulsoup and requests as follows (this is inside a loop that is reading content and writing rows to file, so I'm trying to extract the relevant pieces of code here):

```
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.example.com/community/default.aspx?f=35&m=5555555&p=3"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
posts = soup.find_all('table', class_='PostBox')
if not posts:
    break
for k in posts:
    tds = k.find_all('td')
    userField = tds[0].get_text()
    temp1 = regex.split(userField)
    userName = temp1[0]
    joinDate, postCount = temp1[-1].split("Total Posts : ")
    post = str(tds[3].find('div', class_='PostMessageBody'))
    postMessage, postSig = tds[3].find('div', class_='PostMessageBody').get_text(), ""
    postMessage = postMessage.encode('ascii','ignore')
    postSig = postSig.encode('ascii','ignore')
    writer.writerow([site, userName, joinDate, postCount, postMessage, postSig])
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `([x.text for x in soup.find_all("div")])`

Comment: So this problematic div is always within the first td within a table?

Comment: It's always within the 4th td of the table.